# PayPal NVP: what values can appear in the TimeZone field?

Tags: paypal, timezone, paypal-nvp, nvp

My app uses the **TransactionSearch** and **GetTransactionDetails** functions of PayPal's NVP API. The data that comes back from PayPal includes **Date**, **Time**, and **TimeZone**.
I need to adapt my app to determine the GMT (British) date when each transaction took place.

In the NVP documentation I can find currency codes and country codes, but not time zone codes; and I am aware that they are not well standardised (e.g. "CST" may refer to 4 different zones: see
[looking up time zone standard name by abbreviation in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089700/looking-up-time-zone-standard-name-by-abbreviation-in-net)
).

So: what is the full list of possible values that can appear in PayPal's **TimeZone** field, and their meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response is always in GMT (UTC)

1. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/transaction-search-nvp/
2. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/get-transaction-details-nvp/